# Match expression not starting with

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I need to replace in a string all expressions of type "< input >" not starting with "}".
Which is the right regex expression to do that?

Example

```
strTest = "{ text string }<input> text<input>";
strRegex = ;//which value?
strResult = Regex.Replace(strTest, strRegex , "");
```

strResult should return

```
{ text string }<input> text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want negative lookbehind, e.g.

```
(?<!})<input>
```

You can try it out using RegExr:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to match any  element regardless of type or additional attributes, you could use :

```
strRegex = "<input.*>";
```